# Azure token by using only Azure subscription id

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am using azure rest API for get all resources in my azure portal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list

Currently it will authenticated by access token.  Is there any option to get azure access token by using only subscription id?

Note :Authenticate without using Azure AD.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Is any option create life time access token in azure portal and use that token in code?

Comment: AFAIK, no. If you could accept create the access token manually, why don't you get the token via click the `Try it` button?

Comment: `Is any option create life time access token in azure portal and use that token in code? ` - Why do you want to do that? I am just curious to know your use case. Please edit your question and explain the use case. There may be some viable alternatives available.

Comment: Generate access token without using AD.

Comment: I understand that part. What I want to know is why do you want to get an access token without Azure AD.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any option to get azure access token by using only
>   subscription id?

You can't do it because a user gets authenticated and authorized before accessing an Azure Subscription and information about a user is stored in Azure AD.

> Is any option create life time access token in azure portal and use
>   that token in code?

You can't do that either. Maximum duration for which an access token can be valid is 1 day (minimum is 10 minutes and default is 1 hour). You can read more about token lifetime here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes.